# Slider to go to the end from index[0] React Typescript project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, slider, carousel

I am working on a personal project using `React.js` and `Typescript`. I build a slider that works fine so far, but there is one issue. When the slider is in the position 1, thus `index[0]`, and the user press the "back" `button` to go back one more slide, I would like the slider to go to the end.

This is the code:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const colors: string[] = ["#0088FE", "#00C49F", "#FFBB28"];

export default function App() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  const timeOutRef = useRef<null | number>(null);

  const delay: number = 2500;

  const resetTimeOut = () => {
    if (timeOutRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeOutRef.current);
    }
  };

  const handleArrowRight = () => {
    if (activeIndex === colors.length - 1) {
      setActiveIndex(0);
    } else setActiveIndex(activeIndex + 1);
  };

  const handleArrowLeft = () => {
    if (activeIndex === 0) return;
    setActiveIndex(activeIndex - 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    resetTimeOut();
    timeOutRef.current = setTimeout(
      () =>
        setActiveIndex((prevIndex: number) =>
          prevIndex === colors.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
        ),
      delay
    );
    return () => {
      resetTimeOut();
    };
  }, [activeIndex]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="slideVisible">
        <div
          className="slideContainer"
          style={{ transform: `translate3d(${-activeIndex * 100}%, 0, 0)` }}
        >
          {colors.map((colored, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              className="slide"
              style={{ backgroundColor: colored }}
            ></div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleArrowLeft} className="leftArrow">
          Back
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleArrowRight} className="rightArrow">
          Next
        </button>
        <div className="slideDotsContainer">
          {colors.map((_, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              className={`slideDots ${activeIndex === index ? "active" : ""}`}
              onClick={() => setActiveIndex(index)}
            ></div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, this is a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-1-only-colors-l7eyrv?file=/src/App.tsx:0-2043) link with the css on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how you're just returning in `handleArrowLeft` if `activeIndex === 0`. You can change that to go to last index instead of just return. Like this:

```
  const handleArrowLeft = () => {
    if (activeIndex === 0) {
      setActiveIndex(colors.length - 1)
    } else {
      setActiveIndex(activeIndex - 1);
    }
  };
```

[forked working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-1-only-colors-forked-pe3di7?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks @tanmay I tried that before but it didn't work. I have an array with images in my project. I just updated the CodeSanbox link with some images and you can see that your solution does not work. Thanks tho.

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios you're missing `else` which is present in the answer :)

Comment: Thanks @tanmay sometimes I don't see a thing :]

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios np, happens to the best of us :)